# How to get items from SQL, using linq to sql, where Date is from today to 30 days ahead and return as a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get items from a list using linq to sql where items date property is from today to 30 days ahead, how can I archive this?

I am still new to C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime toDate = fromDate.AddDays(30);
```

and use this appropriately in your linq

```
... .Where(myEntity => myEntity.MyDateProperty >= fromDate 
             && myEntity.MyDateProperty <= toDate)...
```

you can also manipulate `DateTime.Today` in the same manner. This one is better when you don't care about exact time but date.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some query like this

```
    DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime d2 = d.AddDays(30);
    var l = (from c in listname where c.date > d && c.date < d2 select c).ToList();
```

hope this will help.